# How do I select leaf nodes in PHP DomDocument

Tags: php, dom, xpath, domdocument

Assume the following

```
<a>
    <b></b>
    <c></c>
    <d>
        <e></e>
        <f></f>
    </d>
    <g>
        <h>
            <i></i>
        </h>
    </g>
</a>
```

Now, using XPATH in PHP, what is a generic query that will select leaf nodes. In the example above, the result would be nodes **b**, **c**, **e**, **f**, and **i**.

Please note that the xpath query should be generic because I do not have any control over what the input html is, all I need is select the leaf nodes as explained in the above example.

If xpath does not work, what is an alternative solution?

Thanks.

Comment: @bansi
Dear God, you may be right! Damn, I cannot thank you enough. I will check out the answer overthere. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks. I even voted to close it myself.

Comment: nice to hear it helped.